# AWS lambda error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a lambda function which takes apache log files from s3 bucket parses them into JSON documents and adds them to ES, as recommended in the following link :

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-elasticsearch-lambda-samples

but I'm constantly facing the following error :

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'byline'",
    "errorType": "Error",
    "stackTrace": [
        "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:19:18)",
        "Module._compile (module.js:409:26)",
        "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)",
        "Module.load (module.js:343:32)",
        "Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)",
        "Module.require (module.js:353:17)”
    ]
}
```

Kindly, recommend a solution for this.

Comment: Is `byline` an NPM module that you've installed in your app? Are you including it in your deployment package to Lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you aren't including the `byline` package required by the Lambda function. You have to run `npm install` locally and package up your source code and all dependencies into a zip file, and upload that to Lambda. Lambda will not run `npm install` for you and it expects all dependencies to be uploaded. This is documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html).

Comment: i tried uploading all the dependencies, with a little change in the structure of my deployement package. the error tht i'm facing now is :

{
  "errorMessage": null
}

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
npm -s install --production --prefix <folder>
```

then zip it and upload it.